# How do I add a variable amount of rows of the same type?

Tags: postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

I am building an app where a user has cars. This user can own either 1 car or 10 cars or even way more. How do I manage my table so that I can store all the data without hardcoding each column? Should I even be storing them in the same table as my users? Cars can be owned by multiple people too.

Comment: A `users` table, `cars` table, and a `users_cars` table to hold the relationship between the two. Think of each object as a table where that object as attributes (a user has a name and email and other attributes, a car has an engine size and color and other attributes), and also consider that a relationship is an object with its own attributes (the date the relationship was established, and ended, etc).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many